# A pdf document viewing question

Tags: pdf-generation

I have created a pdf in php.To view the next page i have to scroll down and i would like to change this.Is a technique that can allow me scroll from left to right to see the next page and right to left to see the previous page?

Comment: This seems to have more to do with the application you're using to *view* the PDF than how you create the PDF file. And you didn't tell us what viewer you're using—Adobe Reader?

Comment: I am using adobe reader."This seems to have more to do with the application you're using to view the PDF than how you create the PDF file." I agree but what options are there to read and display the pdf doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the "initial view" options are available through the Acrobat UI.  This isn't one of them... save as a "2 up" layout where pages are displayed side by side in pairs.  There's no way to convince it to display "n-up".

The only alternative would be to *brutally hack* up a PDF page that was as wide as N pages.  You'd want some margin in between and some sort of 'page' navigation buttons to move the view around on your horrifically vast page.

Note that there's an implementation-defined limit on the size of a PDF page in any given dimension... lets see...

Ah: 200"x200" using the standard "one point equals 1/72 of an inch".  You can change the definition of a point in your document, but any given page box still cannot exceed 14,400 points in width or height.

So this horrific hack would butt up against the implementation limit at page 22 given 8.5"-wide pages with a half-inch gap between each "page".

I suspect current viewers would have Serious Problems rendering it efficiently, but I'm not about to hack up something that silly to find out.

[/mental-exercise-and-or-torture]

Comment: Thanks,i am working on a hack almighty in javascript,hopes it works.